# Extracting source attribute of generated img by qrcode.js

Tags: javascript, dom, base64

Like I said in the title, my problem is that I get an empty string back.

I'm jusing qrcode.js from https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs .

My Code:

```
    <script src="qrcode.js"></script>
<div id="qr"></div>

<img id="test" src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">


<script type="text/javascript">
var qrCode = new QRCode(
    document.getElementById('qr'),
    {
        text: 'www.google.de',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        onSuccess: (value) => {
            console.log('value',value);
        }
    }
);

</script>

<script>
var test = document.getElementById("test").src;
console.log(test);
var base64 = document.getElementById("qr_neu").src;
console.log(base64);
console.log(typeof base64);
console.log(base64.length);
var dom = document.getElementById("qr_neu").attributes;
console.log(dom);
var code = dom[3];
console.log(code);
</script>
```

The generated QR-Code works fine and in the developer settings in chrome i can see the src of both

Screenshot:
[console in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6T7d.png)

Now I don't understand wha I can't access to the src attribute of the qr-code but on the google img.

I also tried the callbackversion descriped on the github issues section but it doesn't work either.
All i want is the base64 code as var for ther applications.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get an empty string back, even though you can see the src value in your dev tools, is that it takes a very short amount of time to generate the QR-Code.

So `var base64 = document.getElementById("qr_neu").src;`is called before the QR-Code is generated.

Here is a relevant issues on the qrcode.js repository: https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/issues/160.

Here is the solution adapted to your code:

```
const qrDiv = document.getElementById('qr')
var qrCode = new QRCode(
    qrDiv,
    {
        text: 'www.google.de',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        onSuccess: (value) => {
            console.log('value',value);
        }
    }
);
const src = qrDiv.children[0].toDataURL("image/png");
console.info(src);
```